# Using Signalr and knockoutjs for a Live Dashboard

Tags: knockout.js, signalr

I've been having trouble with a project and I've read a lot but I'm still having trouble putting it together.

I have a ticketing system which sends XML notifications to my server which updates a SQL Server database.  I subscribe to the database changes and I am attempting to use SignalR and knockoutjs in order to update the View for all connected clients.

The main problem I'm having is attempting to update the view model which contains a table of Ticket data.  I'm not very strong with javascript so I'm having trouble understanding exactly what I need to do differently.  I know I'm pretty close but need some advice.

Code Behind (in a separate class from hub)

```
      private void BroadcastTableData(DataTable table)
    {
        Clients.All.updateTableData(table);
    }
```

JS

```
$(function () {

var hubProxy = $.connection.notif;

function init() {
    hubProxy.server.getAllTickets().done(function (table) {
        $.each(table, function () {
         //I know this should populate the initial table data
        });
    });
}

hubProxy.client.updateTableData = function (listoftickets) {
//this should update the knockoutjs view model which should be an observable array
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(init);
});
```

And lastly the markup

```
             <tbody data-bind="foreach: tickets">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Message"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: I strongly advice against serialize datatables.  If you need to use them in backend map them to a POCO in the hub before you invoke the clients

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with signalr but you could just put the hubproxy inside your model:

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var hubProxy = $.connection.notif;

    self.tickets = ko.observableArray(model.tickets);

    var init = function(){
        hubProxy.server.getAllTickets().done(function (tickets) {
            self.tickets(tickets);
        });
    };

    hubProxy.client.updateTableData = function (tickets) {
        self.tickets(tickets);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(init);
};
```